# How to create new user and new django allauth social account when given access token over api?

Tags: django, facebook, tastypie, django-allauth

I have a mobile app that allows users to sign up via Facebook.  Once I receive the access token from FB, I send it to the Django backend.

But then what?

Is there a method inside of django-allauth that I can feed the access token to to have it create the new user/social account?

Or do I need to do it all manually?

Answer (score 7):

I always seem to figure out the answers right after I post the question.  In any case, the following is a custom method on UserResource (tastypie api using ApiKeyAuthentication).  Most of it was taken from the login_by_token method in allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook.views.

I won't select my answer as correct for a while in case anyone posts a better answer.

```
def facebook_login(self, request, **kwargs):
    self.method_check(request, allowed=['post'])

    data = self.deserialize(request, request.raw_post_data, format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))

    access_token = data.get('access_token', '')

    from allauth.socialaccount import providers
    from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialLogin, SocialToken, SocialApp
    from allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook.views import fb_complete_login
    from allauth.socialaccount.helpers import complete_social_login
    try:
        app = SocialApp.objects.get(provider="facebook")
        token = SocialToken(app=app,
                            token=access_token)
        login = fb_complete_login(app, token)
        login.token = token
        login.state = SocialLogin.state_from_request(request)
        ret = complete_social_login(request, login)

        #if we get here we've succeeded
        return self.create_response(request, {
                'success': True,
                'username': request.user.username,
                'user_id': request.user.pk,
                'api_key': request.user.api_key.key,
                } ) 
    except:
        # FIXME: Catch only what is needed
        return self.create_response(request, {
                'success': False,
                'reason': "Bad Access Token",
                }, HttpForbidden )
```

Comment: I spent hours puzzling over the allauth code, and eventually came up with something pretty similar to this... but only found this just now. Thanks!

Comment: with the new versions its now `fb_complete_login(request, app, token)`

Answer (score 2):

Modern readers (2017) may want to look at django-rest-auth, which builds on allauth but is built with single page apps in mind:

http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

Working Source Code:
In class UserResource(ModelResource):

```
def override_urls(self):
    return [
        url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/facebook_login%s$" %
            (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
            self.wrap_view('facebook_login'), name="api_facebook_login"),
    ]

def facebook_login(self, request, **kwargs):
    self.method_check(request, allowed=['post'])

    data = self.deserialize(
        request,
        request.raw_post_data,
        format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'applicaton/json'))

    access_token = data.get('access_token', '')

    print(access_token)

    from allauth.socialaccount import providers
    from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialLogin, SocialToken, SocialApp
    from allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook.views import fb_complete_login
    from allauth.socialaccount.helpers import complete_social_login
    try:
        app = SocialApp.objects.get(provider="facebook")
        print(app)
        token = SocialToken(app=app,
                            token=access_token)
        login = fb_complete_login(app, token)
        login.token = token

        login.state = SocialLogin.state_from_request(request)
        ret = complete_social_login(request, login)

        #if we get here we've succeeded
        return self.create_response(request, {
                'success': True,
                'username': request.user.username,
                'user_id': request.user.pk,
                'api_key': request.user.api_key.key,
                } )
    except:
        # FIXME: Catch only what is needed
        return self.create_response(request, {
                'success': False,
                'reason': "Bad Access Token",
                }, HttpForbidden )
```

Then:

> curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST
>   --data '{"access_token":"xxxxxxxx"}' http://xx.xxxxxx.com:8000/api/v1/user/facebook_login/

Test OK, Create User OK.

Thank you.

Comment: What am I missing?  This looks exactly like what I posted.  In any case, I have since realized it's a very bad solution as it has a ton of scenarios where it breaks such as when a user already exists in your db with the same email as their facebook email.

Comment: @KrisF can you post the answer that covers these senarios?

Comment: @rajat Sorry, we never figured it out before moving on to something else entirely.

Comment: @krisf would you mind sharing what was it, I have found a solution but it is a bit hacky, I would also like to move on to something stable.

Comment: @rajat sorry, I meant we moved onto a completely different project that didn't have the same needs.  I never found a solution.